# How do I open Image files with SnippingTool.exe?

Tags: windows, image-editing

I like this software, but I noticed that after you snip--->save--->close the software, you can't open the image again with SnippingTool.exe

Is there a way to achieve this?

I've tried to use the alternate menu right-click "open with" but it's not working.  It just open a new SnippingTool instance without the image I want to open.

Paint does not have the yellow marker I want to use.

Comment: The snipping tool is not an image viewer, it is specifically for getting screen shots.

Answer (score 3):

No, Snipping Tool cannot open an image.

> [Use Snipping Tool to capture screenshots - Windows Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots) Sometimes
>   the easiest way to make a copy of something is to take a snapshot of
>   your screen—this is what Snipping Tool does. Use it to save and share
>   news stories, movie reviews, or recipes.
>
> Capture part or all of your PC screen, add notes, save the snip, or
>   email it right from the Snipping Tool window.

There is no mention of reopening snips in Snipping Tool Help.  There is no "Open" command in the File menu.

Use the Microsoft application Paint to open or edit images you saved with Snipping Tool.

Comment: I saw that there is no open command, that's why I'm here. Maybe someone know a hax to achieve this. Paint does not have the yellow marker I want to use.

Comment: As a workaround, open an existing image in any program and re-snip.  However, a better solution would be to use a more powerful image editing application like GIMP or Paint.NET.

Comment: You could always screenshot the image.... then use that to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

The "Snipping Tool" doesn't save any images, but it puts them into the clipboard. What you ask cannot directly be done, but needs some software which can save images. In this sense, there are **TWO possible solutions**:

### A) Use the "Snip & Sketch" program instead of the Snipping tool

1. Search for the "Snip & Sketch" application which is built into Win 10, and start the app
2. On top left, click on "New". Now the app works like the snipping tool.
3. Crop / sketch / edit
4. Click on "save" and save your picture

### B) Use a third party app

1. Go to Settings -> Clipboard, and turn Clipboard History "ON"
2. Take as many screenshots as you want with the "Snipping Tool".
3. Open your desired application and create a new document.
4. Press Win+V. Select one of the screenshots which are saved in your clipboard history. It will be pasted in your document.
5. Save your image

Answer (score 1):

If you use "Snip & Sketch" you can drag and drop image file to it, or you can right click the image file and select *Open with->Snip & Sketch*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I found that by copying the 'snipped pic' and pasting it into Word you can go from there as to what you want to do.

Comment: How do you go from pasting the image into Word to opening the image again with SnippingTool.exe?